# Windows Firewall blocking FTP on IIS on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I have successfully setup my **FTP** on **Windows Server 2012 R2** by following this [TUTORIAL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh831655.aspx). I am able to see my files by logging in to ftp and after fully disabling **Windows Firewall**. But couldn't connect even if

1. I have allowed ftp through firewall.
2. I have used this [tutorial](http://blog.cirronix.com/2013/10/iis8-ftp-publishing-service-for-server.html) for configuring data channel port.
3. I have made sure that corresponding ports are allowed through FTP.

But as soon as I have enabled **Windows Firewall**, I am unable to connect.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please move your question to [sf] or [su]. It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the default firewall rules don't work.[Slucas Blog](http://blog.slucas.fr/en/tips/ftp-firewall-windows-2008-r2).
I just added new rule for port 21 and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: If you follow the blog instructions and get `Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'unrestricted'`, use `sc.exe`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33785483/21115).

Answer (score 9):

**Restarting FTP Service**

When install new FTP server or change FTP data channel port range --> need restart FTP service to apply. I try this way and it's work.

To restart FTP service go to *Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools and open Services*. Locate ***Microsoft FTP Service*** and click **Restart service**.

Comment: This is the actual answer. If you have just installed it WON'T ACCEPT OUTSIDE CONNECTIONS!!!!!!!!!