# How do i invoke sc create from a powershell script

Tags: powershell, alias, sc.exe

I want to invoke `sc create` from a powershell script. Here is the code.

```
function Execute-Command
{
    param([string]$Command, [switch]$ShowOutput=$True)
    echo $Command
    if ($ShowOutput) {
        Invoke-Expression $Command
    } else {
        $out = Invoke-Expression $Command
    }
}

$cmd="sc create `"$ServiceName`" binpath=`"$TargetPath`" displayname=`"$DisplayName`" "
Execute-Command -Command:$cmd
```

which gives the following error:

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'binpath=...'.
At line:1 char:1
```

What is the problem? What are positional arguments?

Comment: As the error tells you, `sc` is an alias for `Set-Content`. Use the full filename `sc.exe`

Comment: From PS4 on, you can use the `New-Service` cmdlet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849830(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: As an aside: Using script blocks (`{ ... }`) is the preferred way to pass commands as arguments; [`Invoke-Expression` should be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The issue here is not with the `sc` executable. As the error states, `sc` resolves to `Set-Content`. If you issue `Get-Alias -Name sc`, you'll see:

[image: gal sc]

To bypass the alias, use the full name of the executable (including the file extension):

```
PS C:\> sc.exe query wuauserv

SERVICE_NAME: wuauserv
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_PRESHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

---

You might want to use the `-f` operator when constructing your command line arguments, to avoid those annoying quote-escaping back ticks all over the place:

```
$CmdLine = 'sc.exe create "{0}" binpath= "{1}" displayname= "{2}" ' -f $ServiceName,$TargetPath,$DisplayName
Execute-Command -Command $CmdLine
```

Comment: Why Microsoft? Why?

Comment: @Alvaro Not sure I understand the question?

Comment: I'll spell it out for you: why would they create a built-in commandlet alias with a name that conflicts with a commonly used utility that ships with Windows? It seems like a recipe for confusion and annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

The exact command worked for me from a simple Command Prompt console while it fails on PowerShell and VS Code Integrated Terminal. In fact, all `sc` commands had to be run from Command Prompt as Administrator.

```
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\svc\sampleapp.exe"
sc start MyService
```

Answer (score 0):

I know Mathias's script works fine, but there is a reason that it would work and the one posted by Gyozo did not. It has to do with a gotcha in sc.exe.

The space after the equals in binPath and displayName are NOT optional.

For me this snippet would not work:

```
$cmd="sc create `"$ServiceName`" binpath=`"$TargetPath`" displayname=`"$DisplayName`" "
```

However this one would:

```
$cmd="sc create `"$ServiceName`" binpath= `"$TargetPath`" displayname= `"$DisplayName`" "
```

This issue continues to rise up every once in a while to vex me until I remember this.